# Anyway to specify a different user to the host machine for docker volume?

Tags: docker, volume

I don't have /home/abc1 on my host (host name: mzhao).

Then I did this:

```
[mzhao@mzhao ~]$ docker run -it --user nobody -v home/abc1:/home/abc1 centos
bash-4.2$ id
uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody)
```

On my host (mzhao), if I take a look of /home:

```
[mzhao@mzhao home]$ ls -l |grep abc1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root          4096 Apr  2 21:26 abc1/
```

Is there a way to create /home/abc1 under another user on my host?

I am aware of docker user guide mentioned this: 
`auto-creation of the host path has been deprecated.`

But I am just curious. This could happen just because the path does not exist on the host when user "docker command" and specify that directory as a volume.

Comment: I accept the answer by realizing there is no way to specify the owner of the host path of the volume command in "docker run" stage, as @ryekayo's final answer is to create the path and set to the appropriate owner BEFORE all docker command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Dockerfile reference guide, you can specify a user in your Dockerfile:

> USER 
>   USER daemon 
>   The USER instruction sets the user name or UID to use
>   when running the image and for any RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT
>   instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

Refer to the following link for the reference found [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/).

So, for example, you can do something like this:

```
FROM foo
MAINTAINER bar
USER nobody

COPY file /to/point/b
RUN command
ENTRYPOINT["command"]
CMD["command params"]
```

Comment: If that helped answer your question, would you click the check mark please

Comment: Thanks. @ryekayo. but I don't think USER command will affect the real "docker run". 

I gave a try with a docker file with "USER abc" and "VOLUME /home/abc1" like this:

    "USER abc
    VOLUME /home/abc1"

Then ran this command:

    "docker run -it -v /home/abc:/home/abc -v /home/abc1:/home/abc1 centos"

I got the same result:

    "[mzhao@mzhao home]$ ls -lrt /home
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root          4096 Apr  4 06:45 abc1/"

Comment: Hrmmm well if your linking a volume, you should try to change the permissions on your Host machine. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: right. maybe my initial description is not very clear, I just edit my question to clarify. I am wondering any solution in case the directory was not exist at all before issuing "docker run" command.

Comment: You should use the run command in your dockerfile to create the directory while still using the user command in the script

Comment: sorry, don't quite understand how RUN command dockerfile can affect the owner of the files on the host. Let's say, if I have "User abc" and "RUN mkdir /home/abc1", it will only affect "/home/abc1" in the temporary image, right? can you explain in more detail?

Comment: You are correct. But if.your trying to create a directory on your host machine and then use volume to link it in your container, you need to create the directory and user permissions on your host machine first.